# Como comparar un valor contra un conjuto de valores

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones

En javascript quiero hacer una condición en la que compare el inicio de una cadena contra un conjunto de valores, específicamente:

If (str.startsWith('asd') || str.startsWith('qwer') || str.startsWith('zxc'))

Pero quiero que analice mas posibilidades.
Si cargo un array con las posibilidades como se haría el if?
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Actualización:

Como dice Pipe es mejor usar el método some para minimizar las iteraciones:

```
const array = ['asd', 'qwer', 'zxc']
const str = 'qwerty'

if (array.some(elem => str.startsWith(elem))){
  console.log('Verdadero')
} else {
  console.log('Falso')
}
```

---

Puedes usar `map` para aplicar `str.startsWith` a cada elemento del arreglo y luego `.includes(true)` para ver si algún resultado es verdadero:

```js
const array = ['asd', 'qwer', 'zxc']
const str = 'qwerty'

if (array.map(elem => str.startsWith(elem)).includes(true)){
  console.log('Verdadero')
} else {
  console.log('Falso')
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Aunque la respuesta ya esta marcada como apceptada es muy poco óptima en caso de que el array sea muy largo, si tuvieras 1000 elementos, aplicarias el startswith 1000 veces. Es mas optimo usar `some`. `if(array.some(s => str.startsWith(s)){}`. De esta forma si el primer elemento cumple la condición, no se procesará los 9999 restantes.

Comment: @Pipe gracias por el aporte, no concocía el método `some`.

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta es una modificación de la proporcionada por @FedericoMeza porque creo que lo que buscas es saber cual de ellas es verdadera y cual es falsa.

Sería algo así:

```js
const array = ['asd', 'qwer', 'zxc']
const str = 'qwerty'

array.map(elem => {
    if(str.startsWith(elem)) {
        console.log("Verdadero: " + elem)
    } else {
        console.log("Falso: " + elem)
    }
})
```

Practicamente es lo mismo que la otra respuesta, pero cambiando el orden de [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) y del [if()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), conjuntamente con el método [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) para resolver cual de ellas es verdadera y cual es falsa.

No aceptes esta respuesta, acepta la de @FedericoMeza tanto si querias una cosa como la otra, pues me he basado en su respuesta para adaptar la mia.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder. Si podría servir saber cual es verdadera. Pero mi principal duda era como saber si cumplía o no con alguna de las condiciones

Comment: Perfecto, entonces la otra respuesta es la correcta, era por si acaso pues no lo tenia tan claro.